# Catching Google's search "Next Page" - Jsoup Webcrawler

Tags: java, hyperlink, web-crawler, jsoup

I'm building one java webcrawler and I need to catch the "Next Page" link from the Google search I request. For that I was trying to realise one pattern or way to do, but until now I couldn't find any clues about this.

Check out this picture:

[image]

You can test yourself that the "Next Page" is the same link for every number you pass the mouse on. The only think that will change on the link is the part `"Start=(number)"` almost in the end of the link. For every page of search it plus 10 on start, since this is the number of links result per page.

But, the weird part is that this "default" link doesn't come inside the source code of the page when you request the browser to show its code. Maybe this has something with the google index process, but I'm not sure since I'm not an expert programmer yet, specially in Web programmation.

So, anyone has any Idea of how should I solve this?

Comment: i think u can use the answer here [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568518/retrieving-all-links-from-all-pages-of-google-search-result-using-jsoup

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to use the [jsoup.org](http://jsoup.org/) library

Comment: Im already using, but this has nothing with the Jsoup until now since its not clear how to build the logic of the code.