# Retrieving all links from all pages of Google search result using JSoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I have the following code for parsing HTML in java using JSoup.

```
Document linksDoc = null; 
linksDoc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com/search?q=jbutton").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
Elements titles = linksDoc.select("h3.r > a");

for(Element e: titles){
    System.out.println("text"+cnt+": " +e.attr("href"));
  }
```

The problem is that i am able to retrieve only first page search result links. What should i do to get the links from rest of the pages of google search results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `&start=10` to URL if you want to get results from second page. For third page use `&start=20` and so on.

```
Document linksDoc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com/search?q=jbutton&start=10")
        .userAgent("Mozilla").get();
//...
```

Comment: That's what I love about this site -- I get to learn several things new things a day, thanks! (terrible comment, I know, sorry)

Comment: What happens there are less  then 10 results and we use this?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin Didn't test it but I am guessing that you will either get page with information that there are no more results, or you will be redirected to first or last page with results. Anyway I would avoid this kind of situations. You can start browsing results from first page and then simply follow link under *next page* button. For me `doc.select("td.b a.fl").attr("abs:href")` works fine, but depending on your location you may get different HTML code so you may need to inspect parsed document to find it.

Comment: Interesting, how did you found out about this though?

Comment: @Jarrett Hello. Idea about adding `&start=10` parameter to URL came from observing changes in browser after moving to page with next results. BUT this was in times when google had at the bottom links to pages with next results like: `results: 1 2 3 ... 7`. Today google loads next results automatically when you reach bottom of the list. To see from where it *takes it* use browser *inspector* and observe network movement.

Comment: In Chrome when you "inspect" page with google results, select "Network" tab.There you can also select "Fetch/XHR" filter to ignore most irrelevant things like images and scripts. Now after page will load more results (when you browse to bottome) you should see in Network tab some URL used by page to get more results.  BUT be aware that "response" under that URL will probably be JSON instead of HTML.