# JSOUP - Getting pages and links from Google

Tags: jsoup

I am able to retrieve URLs and Titles from Google using `Jsoup` only from the first page. What I want to do is to retrieve data from all pages or from a specific page. My code is as follows:

```
google  = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + searchString + "&num=20";
String charset = "UTF-8";
String userAgent = "ExampleBot 1.0 (+http://example.com/bot)";

Elements links = Jsoup.connect(google + URLEncoder.encode(searchString, charset))
    .userAgent(userAgent).get().select(".g>.r>a");
```

According to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568518/retrieving-all-links-from-all-pages-of-google-search-result-using-jsoup), I should be able to pick specific page changing `&num=20` with `&start=30` but it is not working. Also changing `&num=20` with something like `&num=30` or `&num=40` doesn't affect my result set at all.  Can someone show me where I go wrong?

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: `num` parameter defines how many links will be shown on the webpage. `start` defies from which result to start. So for example `https://www.google.pl/search?q=jsoup&num=5&start=120` will show results from 120-125. Try it with your browser

Comment: Sir that is definitely working now. Could you add this as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num` parameter defines how many links will be shown on the webpage.

`start` defines from which result to start.

So for example https://www.google.pl/search?q=jsoup&num=5&start=120 will show results from 120-125.

Try it with your browser